# Tensorflow and Numpy produce different results

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I've seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1194) that Tensorflow uses matmul in the Dense layer.
I tried to do the same in Numpy but it produces different results.

```
y = np.random.rand(8, 500)
w = np.random.normal(size=(y.shape[1], 128))
y_tf = tf.constant(y, dtype='float32')
yy = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', weights=[w], use_bias=False)
y_tf = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=y_tf)
y_tf = yy(y_tf)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res = sess.run(fetches=y_tf)

y = np.matmul(y, w)
y[y<0] = 0  # relu

np.testing.assert_almost_equal(y, res, decimal=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of this operation is correct and your code is almost correct.
Try replacing

```
yy = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', weights=[w], use_bias=False)
```

with

```
yy = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=None, kernel_initializer=lambda *args, **kwargs: w, use_bias=False)
```

to prevent random initialization of weights and the test will pass.